# Laravel 4 list and detail route

Tags: rest, laravel-4, routes

I want to achieve the following:

devices > Controller@devices

devices/{id} > Controller@devices

Is this possible with Laravel ? I'm trying to map a domotic box with an android application [ImperiHome](http://www.imperihome.com/apidoc/systemapi/#!/devices), and they expect me to have the same route for devices list and for any device action.

So far I've tried this:

```
Route::get('devices/{deviceId}/action/{actionName}/{actionParam?}', 'DomoticzController@devices');
Route::get('devices', 'DomoticzController@devices');
```

But I cannot retrieve the argument when I call the devices/id url

Comment: This should work, how are you trying to retrieve the argument? Try flipping the order of the two routes, when i've done something similar in the past the route that takes arguments is always after the route that doesn't.

Comment: Ok I found a way to make it work, the problem was that I was unable to redirect both routes to same method, so I just used 2 methods (devices & device)

Comment: You can redirect more than one route to a single method. If you expand on your question someone might be able to help you. Explaining what happens when you attempt to access the route with an id would be a good start, so would posting your `devices` method.

Comment: so, the problem, I think, it's that the 1st route need the deviceId & actionName parameter (not optional), and the 2nd route doesn't have arguments, this caused me a php strict error for the missing argument

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to solve the php strict standard error I just splitted the routes to two methods as follows:

**routes.php**

```
Route::get('devices/{deviceId}/action/{actionName}/{actionParam?}', 'DomoticzController@device');
Route::get('devices', 'DomoticzController@devices');
Route::get('rooms', 'DomoticzController@rooms');
//Route::get('action_ret', 'DomoticzController@action_ret');
Route::get('system', 'DomoticzController@system');
Route::get('/', 'DomoticzController@system');
```

**DomoticzController.php**

```
    /**
 * Call for an action on the device identified by $deviceId.
 * @return string Json formated action status.
 */
public function device($deviceId, $actionName, $actionParam = null)
{
    $client = $this->getClient();
    $request = $client->getClient()->createRequest('GET', get_url("json.htm?type=command&param={$actionName}&idx={$deviceId}}&switchcmd=$actionParam"));
    $response = $request->send();
    $input = $response->json();

    // convert to app format
    $output = array('success' => ('OK' === $input['status'] ? true : false), 'errormsg' => ('ERR' === $input['status'] ? 'An error occured' : ''));

    return Response::json($output);
}

/**
 * Retrieve the list of the available devices.
 * @return string Json formatted devices list.
 */
public function devices()
{
    $client = $this->getClient();
    $request = $client->getClient()->createRequest('GET', get_url('json.htm?type=devices&used=true'));
    $response = $request->send();
    $input = $response->json();

    // convert to app format
    $output = new stdClass();
    $output->devices = array();

    foreach ($input['result'] as $device) {
        $output->devices[] = array (
            'id' => $device['idx'],
            'name' => $device['Name'],
            'type' => 'DevSwitch',
            'room' => null,
            'params' => array(),
            );
    }

    return Response::json($output);
}
```

maybe there is a better way to solve this, I would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

If you let both routes use the same controller action, you need to make the parameters optional in the controller I think.

Try this `public function device($deviceId = null, $actionName = null, $actionParam = null)` and see if you still get the PHP strict error.

You can not have a route without parameters be redirected to a controller action that expects parameters. You can, on the other hand, make a route with parameters be redirected to a controller action with optional parameters (this does not mean that your route parameters need to be optional).

Comment: yes that's what I thought, but I rather have 2 methods because the 2nd one must have the first 2 arguments, and with your example I could easily call it without any argument